# Creating a Dictionary from an XML file using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, loops

Please excuse my beginner knowledge of Python. I need to use BeautifulSoup to iterate over a certain element in an XML file.

I am attempting to get information out of an XML file created from a weather website, right now I am saving the XML like this;

```
def aber_forcast():
    url = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=52.41616;lon=-4.064598"
    response = requests.get(url)
    xml_text=response.text
    soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml_text, "xml") 
    f = open('file.xml', "w")
    f.write(soup.prettify())
    f.close()
    return (soup)
```

I am attempting to count the occurrences on the element 'symbol id'. I'm going to need to create a graph of the symbol id and how many times it occurs throughout the XML. I can manage to get all the symbol_id's into one list using;

```
with open ('file.xml') as file:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file, "xml")
    symbol_id = soup.find_all("symbol")   
    print(symbol_id)
```

There are 'Cloud', 'Rain' etc and an associated ID number that goes with it, having looked through stackoverflow, I'm assuming it's something like the below code I will need to create a dictionary of the associated numbers and ID's then count up the iterations.

```
def parseLog(file):
    file = sys.argv[1]
    handler = open(file).read()
    soup = Soup(handler)
    for sym in soup.findAll('symbol'):
        msg_attrs = dict(sym.attrs)
        f_user = sym.find('symbol id').user
        f_user_dict = dict(f_user.attrs)
        print ((f_user_dict[u'symbols'], sym.find('number').decodeContents())
```

Any help or advice would be great sorry if the question doesn't make much sense I'm still new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure what you are looking for but a simple iteration through the list counting the occurrences of the ids would look like this.

```
#get data
url = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=52.41616;lon=-4.064598"
response = requests.get(url)
xml_text=response.text
soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml_text, "xml") 
symbol_id = soup.find_all("symbol")

# create dictionary
d = {}
for item in symbol_id:
    d[item['id']] = d.get(item['id'], 0) + 1

print(d)

{'Cloud': 15,
 'Drizzle': 9,
 'DrizzleSun': 6,
 'LightCloud': 2,
 'LightRainSun': 2,
 'PartlyCloud': 13,
 'Rain': 1,
 'Sun': 18}
```

You can also do this in one line with `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([x['id'] for x in soup.find_all("symbol")])
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I'm looking for, it looks so easy when you know how, just a single line of code. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: No problem. See the one line answer that I added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xmltodict` https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict

```
xmltodict.parse("""
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<person>
<name>john</name>
<age>20</age>
</person>""")
# {u'person': {u'age': u'20', u'name': u'john'}}`
```